# How to convert 2 Dimensional latitudes and longitudes arrays in netcdf file to normal 1D array?

Tags: python, coordinates, latitude-longitude, netcdf, python-xarray

[PHOTO OF DATA IN THE NETCDF4 FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHBi5.png)

I downloaded SEVIR Satellite data, and upon Opening the NETCDF4 file found the latitudes and longitudes were 2Dimensional arrays. I need to convert this to one dimensional Latitudes and Longitudes for further. Can someone help me with this?

Data Can be downloaded form this link : http://msgcpp-ogc-archive.knmi.nl/thredds-ar/fileServer/ARCHIVE_SEVIR_OPER_R___MSGCPP__L2/2019/08/21/SEVIR_OPER_R___MSGCPP__L2__20190821T000000_20190822T000000_0001.nc

Comment: Do not include photo or links on questions. Please copy the data directly in your question: we can copy and test, and also copy and include the relevant part in the answer. In any case: I doesn't understand the question (and I'll not open random links from random persons).

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi here is the link from where you can download the data : http://msgcpp-ogc-archive.knmi.nl/thredds-ar/fileServer/ARCHIVE_SEVIR_OPER_R___MSGCPP__L2/2019/08/21/SEVIR_OPER_R___MSGCPP__L2__20190821T000000_20190822T000000_0001.nc

Comment: @Giacomo The question is that in this file the latitude and longitude are 2 dimensional data arrays like lot(x,y) | lat(x,y) ; usually this data is one dimensional; so I need some method to convert it

Comment: Please include sample of data in your question. The question (so this page) should be self descriptive (and a 5.4 GB file is not what we want). In any case I do not know. You should check the description (metadata) of the dataset, and so find out the structure. Maybe it is the region (so you have a square), but x seems equal to -y, so ... it is strange. You need the metadata (also to see how to interpret the latitude and longitude [there are many possibilities]: the datum)